# Eliminating spaces and words starting with particular chars from JAVA string

Tags: java, string

Eliminating spaces and words starting with particular chars from JAVA string.

With the following code spaces between string words are eliminated:

```
String str1= "This is symbel for snow and silk. Grapes are very dear"
String str2=str1.replaceAll(" ","");
System.out.println(str2);
```

It gives this output:-

```
output:
Thisissymbelforsnowandsilk.Grapesareverydear
```

But I want to eliminate all the words in str1 starting with char  's' (symbel snow  silk) and char  'd' (dear) to get the following output:-

```
output:
Thisisforand.Grapesarevery
```

How it can be achieved by amending this code?

Comment: Look up "Word Boundry + regex" my friend.. Who knows, you might not even need " "

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) may help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
String str1= "This is symbel for snow and silk. Grapes are very dear";
System.out.print(str1.replaceAll("[sd][a-z]+|[ ]+",""));
```

**[Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/jT7mP9)**

Comment: Can you explain this regex for the original poster?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to use a **Regular Expression** also known as a Regex.

These are designed specifically for complex search and replace functionality in strings.

This one:

```
"([sd]\\w+)|\\s+"
```

matches a word group indicated by the parentheses () starting with 's' or 'd' followed by one or more "word" characters `(\\w = any alpha numeric or underscore)` *OR* one or more whitespace characters `(\\s = whitespace)`.  When used as an argument to the String replaceAll function like so:

```
s.replaceAll("([sd]\\w+)|\\s+", "");
```

every occurance that matches either of these two patterns is replaced with the empty string.

There is comprehensive information on regexes in Oracle's java documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Although they seem cryptic at first, learning them can greatly simplify your code. Regexes are available in almost all modern languages so any knowledge you gain about regexes is useful and transferable.

Furthermore, the web is littered with handy sites where you can test your regexes out before committing them to code.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
s = s.replaceAll("([sd]\\w+)|\\s+", "");
```

Comment: this should be `[sd]` not `[sg]`

Comment: this answer doesn't really explain anything to the original poster

Comment: @MattCoubrough Should it? There are better places than SO to read up on regexes, imVHo.

Comment: @okiharaherbst Yes. Otherwise they'll have to post another question the next time they need a regex solution... "try this" answers are generally frowned upon. Just because question quality is dropping, no need for answer quality to be poor too.

Comment: @MattCoubrough Fine. Just let them ask a "How do regexes work?" question and see it closed in less than 5 min. This question-answer pair is the perfect example for SO: it's succinct and precise. If you're using `replaceAll` without reading the API, you can't hold anyone but yourself responsible for it.